# expire_action doesn't delete cached page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I use cache_sweeper, caches_action. After update I need to reset cache for object.

```
class ProductSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Product

  def after_update(product)
    expire_action(:controller => "/product", :action => "show", :url => product.url_was, :category => product.cats.first.url)
    expire_action(:controller => '/catalog', :action => 'show', :url => product.cats.first.url)
  end
end
```

After update in console I can see log:

```
Expire fragment views/localhost:3000/catalog/cat1/prod123456 0.1ms
Expire fragment views/localhost:3000/catalog/cat1 0.0ms
```

, but files doesn't being deleted, and hitting those urls return old cached pages.. What the hell ?(

Cached files are being saved in %rails_root%/tmp/cache ; 
Rails 3.2.19 and ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved that problem, there was a stupid mistake in `product.cats.first.url`; cache has been cleared only for one category. If you have similar problem - double check that requesting url and cleared url are same.